# Create external link to BIM360 document

Tags: api, integration, autodesk-forge, erp, autodesk-bim360

I am researching to see if this is possible.  I am new to the Forge API and Revit/Bim360 in general so my apologies if I am not using the correct terminology.  I have successfully made API calls using Postman to  BIM360 to pull back project information.

What I would like to do is construct a URL from within our ERP application that passes the external project id and the sheet name into a web application and to have that web application take the user to the bim360 markup viewer of that item.

So user would be looking at a work order in our manufacturing system, click the link for "View Production Ticket" and a screen would pop up, ask the user to login to BIM360 if they haven't already, and open the bim360 viewer.

Answer (score 0):

To do so, I would like to advise you to integrate the following Forge APIs instead in your ERP system, not embed BIM360 to the ERP system directly:

1. Forge OAuth API to fetch 3 legged-token with user login (their Autodesk account)
2. Forge Data Management API to obtain hubs, project, items, version, and derivative file links of the model file of your BIM360 account.
3. View your model (derivative urn) via Forge Viewer

Here is a tutorial for you http://learnforge.autodesk.io/ and hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks Eason,  I was hoping to bring the user into native BIM360 so that they could use the markups and issues entry from within the application but I suppose if this is the only way right now.  I do know its possible to create issues from a custom application so that might be the route I have to go.